# Get value of NSTextfield by tag number in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, nstextfield

I have a problem : How can i do If i want get value of NSTextField by tag number?

I create NSTextField dynamically and set tag for it by this code :

```
for(int i=0; i<number;i++)
{
    NSTextField *ssid = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (10,label_Y,150,25)];
    [ssid setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SSID %d :",i +1]];
    [ssid setSelectable:NO];
    ssid.tag = i;
    [ssid setEditable:NO];
    [ssid setBordered:NO];
    [ssid setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [ssid setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
    [contentView addSubview:ssid];
    label_Y -=30;
    [ssid release];

   NSTextField *ssid2 = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect (10,label_Y,150,25)];
    [ssid2 setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SSID %d :",i +1]];
    [ssid2 setSelectable:NO];
    ssid2.tag = i;
    [ssid2 setEditable:NO];
    [ssid2 setBordered:NO];
    [ssid2 setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [ssid2 setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];
    [contentView addSubview:ssid2];
    label_Y -=30;
    [ssid2 release];
```

}

And then i want get value of each NSTextField But i don't know how to get value of NStextfield by tag number? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the tag is 7.

```
[contentView viewWithTag:7]
```

That returns the tag, if a subview (including the view itself, `contentView` in this case) has this tag or nil if none is found. You are in charge with making sure to have the tags unique. For that you should never ever use 0 as tag value because 0 is the default value `[contentView viewWithTag:0]` would return `contentView` unless you set its tag to something else.